# how to add column names when exporting a large table in IBM betezza aginity sql database workbench

Tags: sql, database, export, netezza

I need to export a table (60 GB) from IBM netteza aginity sql database workbench to a csv file.

But, the column names are missing even though I set up "skip row" as 0.

Because the file is too large, I cannot open and edit it in Excel or notepad/notepad++.

How to add the column names ?

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no feature to self-document exported data from Aginity Workbench. Also, as far as I know the "Skip Rows" feature in the export function is disabled, and has nothing to do with adding column documentation. For imports it would certainly let you skip over a column header row.

EDIT: With the GA of NPS 7.2 an "IncludeHeader" option has been added to the available external table options that will create a commented header line in the output file.  It may take Aginity a while to update Workbench to directly support this feature, but you can always just copy the code it generates and add that option manually.

You can create a standalone header file and the use a command prompt copy in windows to append the two files together without opening either, like so:

```
copy header_file.txt+data_file.txt new_file.txt
```

I have used two different methods to create a header row.

The first is to run the query used for your export with "LIMIT 1", then select all of the output in the output window, right click and select "copy with headers". Then you can paste the output into Excel and tack on the header list.

The second method is to generate an ordered list of columns in the table, and then transpose that output in a spreadsheet from a column to a row.  You can use the following code snippet to generate that output.

```
SELECT attname,
   atttype,
   attnotnull,
   attnum
FROM _v_relation_column_def
WHERE attnum > 0
AND objid    =
   (
      SELECT objid
      FROM _v_obj_relation
      WHERE objname = ^TABLENAME_TO_EXPORT^
      AND schemaId IN ( current_schemaid,
                       4,
                       5 )
      AND objclass NOT IN (4919,
                           4917)
      ORDER BY schemaId DESC
   )
ORDER BY attnum
```

Neither of these approaches are perfect fits, but I thought I'd share what I had.